# v6 react-router returns `null` state in location when state given a function property

Tags: react-router

I am doing a nested routers layout. I have a parent component that needs to render a list of N children. Additionally, I want to pass a function `(id: string) => Observable<X>` from parent to child. Currently, I am doing:

```js
// parent.tsx

function getStream(id: string): Observable<X>; // assume exists

function Parent() {
  const child_links = children_data.map(child_data => (
    <Link
      to={...}
      state={{ child_data, getStream }}
    />
  ));

  ...
  // return some output with `child_links` embedded
}
```

```js
// child.tsx
import { useLocation } from 'react-router';

function Child() {
  const location = useLocation();

  // The issue I am facing:
  // returns { child_data: {...} } if I choose to omit `getStream` in `Parent`;
  // returns `null` when `getStream` included; expected `getStream` to exist and be function I passed
  console.log(location.state);

  // some arbitrary rendering
}
```

```js
//index.tsx, where Router defined:

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Parent />}>
          <Route path='children/:child_id' element={<Child />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Other ridiculous things I have tried:

- Wrapping the function in an object, passed through constructor. Effect: causes same `null` state problem.
- Wrapping the function in an object, as a method. Effect: does not cause `null` state, but the associated property of `state` ends up just being an empty object. this tells me that react-router is likely doing less-than-smart hash object cloning.

Things I *think* would be better avoided:

- Just creating a static controller object that serves up the `Observable`
- Using the `Context` system from `react`

Am I abusing `state` here? If `Links` are to be used in a nest router setting, am I expected not to share upstream state with downstream components?

Thanks!

Comment: This part of the docs might help: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#note-on-link-to-values

Comment: Functions are not serializable, they can't be sent through route state. You could certainly pass the `id` in route state for the child to invoke `getStream` with.

Comment: That seems like the most sensible solution, Drew. As I look at it more. Thanks for the second set of eyes.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @DrewReese, functions are not serializable, and thus cannot be sent through route state. Therefore, my solution to this issue is simply to introduce a `getStream` function in a location accessible to the `Child`.